# How to save JSON output into a dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, python-requests

I was wondering how I would get the output in my for statement to save as a dictionary as I will need to iterate the output later.

```py
def get_assets_for_group():
    url5 = server + path1
    response = requests.request("GET", url5, headers=headers, verify=False)
    data = response.json()
    for resources in data['resources']:
        data = response.json()
```

Comment: `data` already is a dictionary, could you clarify your question?

Comment: so i am trying to use this output to iterate through the id numbers in it to pull information from each of them. How would i go about doing this. I assume another get request but how do i populate the ids in data to the url needed.

Comment: is the id contained in `data['resources']`? Can you extract it from there and add it to the url that you use for the next request?

Comment: yes, the ids are all in there. The url needs the specific id that is contained in that output. would i possibly be able to add them in as a string or is that not possible?

Comment: It is possible to add two strings, the same way you're doing it in the line `url5 = server + path1` you could do it with a id string like `id_url = base_url + id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Writing dict to a json file**

[Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html][1]

```
import json

json.dump(json_Data_Variable,open('dst.json','w'))
```